# Autofac IAutofacActionFilter execution order for Web API 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, autofac

Are there any ways to set the order of execution on web api action filters registered with Autofac?
Currently, if I register the following:

```
builder.Register(x => new MyFirstAttribute(x.Resolve<IMyService>())).AsWebApiActionFilterFor<ApiController>().InstancePerRequest();
builder.Register(x => new MySecondAttribute(x.Resolve<IMyService>())).AsWebApiActionFilterFor<ApiController>().InstancePerRequest();
```

it is 'unknown' which will be executing first and second. Even if I'd create a new FilterProvider which orders them in a specific way it will not work due to [removal of any custom IFilterProvider](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.WebApi/blob/master/src/Autofac.Integration.WebApi/RegistrationExtensions.cs#L227) and [a private ActionDescriptorFilterProvider](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.WebApi/blob/master/src/Autofac.Integration.WebApi/AutofacWebApiFilterProvider.cs#L54).

Comment: Possibly related: https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.WebApi/issues/7

Comment: Looking at [the source](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.WebApi/blob/master/src/Autofac.Integration.WebApi/AutofacWebApiFilterProvider.cs) It appears things should run in reverse registration order (last to first). When running your tests, do you find the behavior _inconsistent_ or just _unknown to you_?

Comment: It is unknown to me by looking at the code snippet and by reading the autofac documentation. It runs pretty consistent in reverse order (could you pinpoint which line) - but what guarantees this behavior won't change to a natural registration order. I could guarantee the order if i could override the private ActiondescriptorFilterProvider and set the order myself - registering the attributes in reverse vs e.g. .AsWebApiActionFilterFor<ApiController>(order: 1); I'd prefer the latter, or implement my own IFilterProvider it would use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is currently no way to **manually** specify the order in which registered filters run.

Filters get resolved in the same way other dependencies get resolved using the `IEnumerable<T>` [implicit relationship type](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html#supported-relationship-types). This happens [in the AutofacWebApiFilterProvider](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.WebApi/blob/f13f0dda717d2918b409198938b56cbe4b539f24/src/Autofac.Integration.WebApi/AutofacWebApiFilterProvider.cs#L126). As with regular filters, it's more complex than just "run in XYZ order" - there's controller vs. action scoping to take into account as well.

So, say you registered these:

```cs
builder.RegisterType<LoggingFilter>()
    .AsWebApiActionFilterFor<ValuesController>()
    .InstancePerApiRequest();
builder.RegisterType<AuthenticationFilter>()
    .AsWebApiActionFilterFor<ValuesController>()
    .InstancePerApiRequest();
builder.RegisterType<ErrorFilter>()
    .AsWebApiActionFilterFor<ValuesController>(c => c.Get(default(int)))
    .InstancePerApiRequest();
builder.RegisterType<RoundingFilter>()
    .AsWebApiActionFilterFor<ValuesController>(c => c.Get(default(int)))
    .InstancePerApiRequest();
```

Web API filters run controller level then action level; Autofac filters run in reverse registration order. If someone calls the `Get` action on the `ValuesController` the filters will run:

- AuthenticationFilter
- LoggingFilter
- RoundingFilter
- ErrorFilter

However, it's sometimes not as straightforward as that, since if you use an extension like `PreserveExistingDefaults` it internally changes the order of registrations to put the `PreserveExistingDefaults` registration last.

That sort of registration ordering complexity with handling defaults and so forth is why I can't point you to *a line* of code.You *can* look at the [CollectionRegistrationSource](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/blob/e70f7248b16e8603b3fc01446f5aa9e078c6c76a/src/Autofac/Features/Collections/CollectionRegistrationSource.cs) which is responsible for resolving the `IEnumerable<IActionFilter>` collections as part of the filter provider. You can also look [at the filter provider](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.WebApi/blob/f13f0dda717d2918b409198938b56cbe4b539f24/src/Autofac.Integration.WebApi/AutofacWebApiFilterProvider.cs) to see how things happen.

If you need to manually specify order, you'll have to write your own extension to the `AutofacWebApiFilterProvider` or, if extension doesn't work, roll your own. If you get it working well in a nice fluent manner, we'd be happy to [take a pull request](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.WebApi/pulls).