# Multiple IAutofacActionFilter execution order

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have multiple action filters which are implemented from IAutofacActionFilter. I want to control the order of execution. So that my Logging action filter will execute first before another action filter. Please.

I want to implement this globally. I don't want to specify any attribute on each method of the controller as I have 100 controllers with 10000 controller methods.

Comment: It looks like there is currently no way to do this. Please see [Autofac IAutofacActionFilter execution order for Web API 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35797079/autofac-iautofacactionfilter-execution-order-for-web-api-2)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Autofac IAutofacActionFilter execution order for Web API 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35797079/autofac-iautofacactionfilter-execution-order-for-web-api-2)